# Disable E501 line too long pylint warnings in the Google Cloud Shell Code Editor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pylint, google-cloud-shell, pylintrc

When I view a python file in the cloud shell editor, long lines are marked with a green line and a warning [image: screen shot of editor warning]

I find this warning distracting.  On a modern wide screen, \

long lines are clearer \

than broken ones.

I can remove the lint warning by appending # noqa: E501 to each long line But this is *almost* as distracting.

```
x = 'this is a rather long line to show the E501 warning which will appear around here'   # noqa: E501
```

Is there a way to configure pylint used by the cloud shell editor to suppress this globally?